Azure Bot is not receiving scheduled messages; otherwise, it is working fine
he bot subscription, our bot is working fine, sending cards and other responses as per the settings, but it is not receiving the scheduled messages that are sent daily through Lambda functions.
receive daily messages, even if I change the bot. I am still facing the same issue.

Verify that the Messaging endpoint is correct and responds as expected

Ensure that your Azure Bot Service is running and accessible by your lambda function. Verify that the Messaging endpoint is correct and responds as expected.
Check the logs in the Azure portal for any errors or warnings that might indicate why the bot isn't receiving messages. You can find these logs under the Bot Service resource >> Monitor >> Diagnostic settings >> And add the logs to Storage account or any other given storage identify the reason for messages isn't received by bot.

Verify that there are no network issues or firewall rules blocking the communication between the Lambda function and your bot.

I am facing 'Failed to decrypt conversation ID"
